# How to call a controller withour going to the url in magento

Tags: php, magento, prototypejs

I am new to magento. I needed to know if its possible to call a controller without going to url. What i want to do is to call the controller but staying on the same page. I have a form on the front end which accepts user input and than call a controller to save the data in the database by using models. Eveything works ok but my problem is that when user click on submit button the user goes to the controller url but i want to stay on the same page but call the controller. here is my code

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>


<form id="test" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('pricenotify/pricenotify/db') ?>" method="post">

            <label for="price">Price *</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="" class="required-entry validate-number"/><br />
            <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="required-entry validate-email"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="propri" name="propri" value="<?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?>" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" />


</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//< ![CDATA[
var customForm = new VarienForm('test',true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean to request the URL with AJAX?

Comment: i think maybe you are right if i use AJAX to call the action controller. It should call the controller without taking the user to actual controller url...

Comment: i have not used ajax any idea how do you do it...just direct me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to [convert to AJAX](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/prototype/request/) is to modify the button like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>"
    onclick="if(customForm.validator && customForm.validator.validate()) this.form.request(); return false;" />
```

It doesn't do anything with the results, just calls the relevant controller/action.

Comment: hey thanks waoo man its so easy...i gotta learn ajax..thanks you so much

Comment: there seems to be a problem if i use AJAX. Magento from validation is not working anymore

Comment: That's a good point. Because the form never submits (the event returns `false` instead) the usual validation step is missed. I have updated my answer to validate _before_ the AJAX.